# GetElementsByName returned Nothing

Tags: vba, dom, web-scraping

I am trying to use VBA to log into some website. And I would like to fill in the username input box. But the getElementsByName returns Nothing:

```
Sub login()
    Const Url$ = "https://10.130.44.140:5461/hkwp/CP"

    Dim UserName As String, Password As String

    UserName = "qwe"
    Password = "qwe"

    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
        .navigate Url
        ieBusy ie

        On Error Resume Next
        For i = 1 To 10 'Loop ten times to ensure the certifiacate will be bypassed.
        .Document.getElementsByName("overridelink").Item.Click
        Next i
        On Error GoTo 0

       .Visible = True

        Set objInputs = ie.Document.getElementsByName("username")
        For Each ele In objInputs
            Debug.Print ele.Value
        Next

        Dim oLogin As Object, oPassword As Object
        Set oLogin = .Document.getElementsByName("username")(0)
        Set oPassword = .Document.getElementsByName("Password")(0)

        oLogin.Value = UserName
        oPassword.Value = Password
        .Document.forms(0).submit
    End With
End Sub

Sub ieBusy(ie As Object)
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

And The web source

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="https://webportaluat.cigna.com.hk/pkmslogin.form">
<input type="HIDDEN" name="login-form-type" value="pwd">
<div align="center">
<div class="outer_container">
<div class="">
<table width="968px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#FFFFFF" vspace="0">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td width="968" height="68" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <div style="float: left"></div>
        <div style="float: right" class="link_11_grey header_line">
            <a href="/hkwp/HKWPCAP/unsecure/ForwardToLoginPage.do?actionParam=forwardToLoginPage&amp;localeId=zh_HK">中文</a>
         </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
<table height="51" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td width="322" class="left_menu_nav">
        <table width="278" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td colspan="4" align="left"><img src="/hkwp/HKWPCAP/images/en/login_cignaHK.png"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="left">
                <td height="10" colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="left">
                <td width="23">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="71" align="left" valing="middle"><span class="font_11_grey_b">Username</span></td>
                <td width="161"><input name="username" type="text" class="login_field_frame font_11_grey"></td>
                <td width="32">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="left">
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left" valing="middle"><span class="font_11_grey_b">Password</span></td>
                <td><input name="password" type="password" class="login_field_frame font_11_grey" onkeyup="javascript:forwardToLogin(event);"></td>
                <td><a href="javascript:submitForm()" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('go','','/HKWPCAP/images/en/common/com_btnGoR.gif',1)"><img src="https://webportaluat.cigna.com.hk/hkwp/HKWPCAP/images/en/common/com_btnGo.gif" name="go" width="19" height="19" border="0" id="go"></a> <img src="/hkwp/HKWPCAP/images/en/common/com_btnGoR.gif" width="19" height="19" border="0" name="goR" id="goR" style="display: none"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><img src="/hkwp/HKWPCAP/images/en/login_line.gif" width="287" height="2" vspace="10"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="3">
                <table width="154" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="left_menu_nav_box">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td width="12"><img src="/hkwp/HKWPCAP/images/en/common/com_greenArrow.gif"></td>
                        <td width="142" class="link_11_blue"><a href="/hkwp/HKWPCAP/unsecure/Registration.do?actionParam=forwordToRegistration" class="font_11_grey_b">Registration</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="/hkwp/HKWPCAP/images/en/common/com_greenArrow.gif"></td>
                        <td class="link_11_blue"><a href="/hkwp/HKWPCAP/unsecure/guideLineEn.do" target="_blank">User Guide</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="/hkwp/HKWPCAP/images/en/common/com_greenArrow.gif"></td>
                        <td class="link_11_blue"><a href="/hkwp/HKWPCAP/unsecure/ForgotPassword.do?actionParam=forward">Forget Password</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        </td>
        <td><img src="/hkwp/HKWPCAP/images/en/HKWP_MAIN_LR.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>






<div class="footer_container">
<table width="100%">
    <tbody><tr class="font_11_grey link_11_grey">
        <td width="11%" align="center">© 2012 Cigna</td>
        <td width="78%" align="center" class="footer_font"><a href="../unsecure/ConditionViewStandalone.do" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions</a> | <a href="../unsecure/Faq.do" class="footer_font" target="_blank">FAQ</a></td>
        <td width="11%"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Based on my understanding, I inspected the two input boxes, which with Name username and password, but when the getElement method return Nothing. I also tried to print out the inputbox, but it also have no effect. It seems that username is not the correct index I should look for.

Comment: @Comintern I've post the full code here. https://gist.github.com/SUNJIANZHI/c193b4936db4ce3851858df9dfee0f83

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML in your question. Not as an image by the way but using the snippet tool. There could be parent frame/iframe/form tags to consider, or a dynamically constructed element....

Comment: @Comintern I am not sure if you could access the website I embedded. Seems that it is an internal website. If you cannot access the website, I will also copy the front-ended code for you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't use the page source but actually right click inspect and copy the html body element/entire document. If it is really long then include the relevant parts bearing in mind my comment above.

Comment: Is the page completely loaded when you call `.getElementsByName("username")`? It isn't clear from the code, but you're jamming on the `overridelink` button(?). Do you just need a wait (`ieBusy ie`) to ensure that any navigation caused by the click is completed?

Comment: @Comintern It should throw an element not found error in that case, no? But yes, absolutely should be another wait for page load after click event ( While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend)

Comment: @QHarr <input name="username" type="text" class="login_field_frame font_11_grey"> I think this is the input box related to my question. https://10.130.44.140:5461/hkwp/CP This is the website I would like to log in. I could not copy the whole form code here due to the character limit.

Comment: The overridelink is to bypass the certificate error, since this website does not have a valid certificate.

Comment: You would post html using [edit] into your question. @Comintern is right about adding a wait for page load after a click event. You may then try IE.document.querySelector("[name='username']").Value = "xyz"   , but this is guesswork without seeing the html structure.

Comment: @Comintern I tried another ieBusy, but it still return the run time error 91 Object variable not set

Comment: Have you tried loading it in a browser? I'm getting a gateway timeout on your link.

Comment: When you right click inspect is the element in question inside a parent frame/iframe/form tag?

Comment: @Comintern I’ve loaded this web in IE and Chrome. The address could be an internal use and that’s why you could not access this web. I will post the web source code later for your reference.

Comment: You could access through this link[link](https://hk.member.cigna.com/hkwp/HKWPCAP/unsecure/ForwardToLoginPage.do?actionParam=forwardToLoginPage&ssoId=unauthenticated&ssoId=a4wong)

Answer (score 1):

There is a parent `form` tag to navigate first. After navigating that I use a CSS attribute selector of `[name='username']` to target the element by its `name` attribute and value.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub LoginPage()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://hk.member.cigna.com/hkwp/HKWPCAP/unsecure/ForwardToLoginPage.do?actionParam=forwardToLoginPage&ssoId=unauthenticated&ssoId=a4wong"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document.getElementsByTagName("form")(0) '<==Navigate parent form tag
            .querySelector("[name='username']").Value = "myUserName"
            .querySelector("[name='password']").Value = "myPassword"
        End With
        Stop                                     '<==Delete me after inspecting
        '.Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try this?